Why is logarithm with base 10 having number greater than 1 always positive?
Consider logarithm with base 10 and number k
Why will it always be positive if k>1 and negative if k<1?

Consider positive vs negative powers of ten.

This is equivalent to asking why $10^x > 1$ if $x > 0$ and $10^x < 1$ if $x < 0$. Does that make more sense?
